# How to not rerender a component when revisiting a page in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

When I visit another page and come back, I want to express the Google Maps coordinates and data that I had.
There's a lot of data that needs to be handled to use the Store, so it's hard to use.
I wonder if there is a way to recycle pages without erasing them from DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to preserve the page's content as is while navigating, you may use `keep-alive` which will cache the route's content. See docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components).

However, my personal experience is that caching Vue or Nuxt pages with `keep-alive` sometimes leads to unexpected bugs in my applications since oftentimes I write code with the expectation that all the values I defined in *data()* are going to have the default value. But that's not the case when caching the components.
As you've said, this requirement often arises when some expensive data have been fetched. I prefer to either cache this fetch result (mostly in local storage) or in Vuex Store. One can then safely destroy the component when navigating away and reuse the cached data when navigating back, but the component will be otherwise initialized with the default *data()*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keep-alive` attribute:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive
Then your `mounted` lifecycle will called only once.

**But**, there is no prevention to store huge amount of data in the `vuex store`.

Comment: Thank you Ballon Ura :)